# Anyone have issues with NIO/IPV6 AND being disconnected from network?

Tags: java, nio

I have a test case that works in these situations

1. ipv4, online, nio  (-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true)
2. ipv4, offline(disconnect wifi), nio (-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true)
3. ipv6, online, nio

THEN, the final ipv6, offline(no wifi connected) literally never connects and just hangs until timeout.  the first call so SocketChannel.connect returns false which is fine so then it initiates an async connect with SelectableChannel.register.  Unfortunately, it hangs somewhere in jdk code.....hmmmm, I guess I can do a stack dump next and add more info.

Has anyone seen this issue before?
jdk 9.0.4

(I guess I also have to pull the plug and upgrade to jdk10 which hopefully will be easy - fingers crossed).

UPDATE 1: Ok Profiler was no help since it's nio, it's async meaning it sits on the selector waiting(expected and expected to fire is all) and the other thread sits on a future waiting for it to resolve until the selector fires and finishes the connection which never happens(only offline).  I guess I will upgrade jdk and test that too.

UPDATE 2: Upgraded to jdk12 and same results.

Does anyone else have tests over localhost where server binds to port 0 and client connects in to the port that ends up getting bound where the client is in nio AND using ipv6?  It is very annoying when a test suite doesn't work offline and only works online so I am trying to fix that.

thanks,
Dean

Comment: Is your test binding/connect to an IPv6 link-local address when the wiki is off? Which operating system is this. Have you tried to specify the scope id to identity the loopback interface?